# How to create custom hotkey for printScreen

Tags: screenshot

I want to use the Lightshot app for taking screenshots. I was able to install it with wine and it's working fine. I uninstalled gnome-screenshot but now I want to use the lightshot app when I press Print Screen. How can I achieve that?